useEffect in Nextjs 14 - Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node' - Link
I get this error with any player that I try to initiate within the useEffect :

NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.

my nextjs 14 client component :
"use client";

import "plyr/dist/plyr.css";
import Plyr from "plyr";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const VideoPlayer = () => {
  const videoRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (videoRef.current) {
      const player = new Plyr(videoRef.current);

      // return () => {
      //     player.destroy();
      // };
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <video ref={videoRef} className="plyr" controls>
        <source src={"/test.mp4"} type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
    </>
  );
};

export default VideoPlayer;

The issue happens when I click on the next Link tag when I'm on the same page as the player, I even tried to add a return statement to the useEffect but it doesn't work because it rendered two times, I stopped the reactStrictMode inside the next js config but nothing happens, it only gets solved when I replace the Link tag with regular a tag
My App Structure:
<MyServerComponent>
  <MyPlayerInClientComponent>
  <Link src={"/"} /> <--- The error happens when I click on the link tag while being on the same page as the player
</MyServerComponent> 


What happens when you use that returned function in the useEffect ? Note that the official documentation under section "Plugins & Components" refers to an existing React wrapper for plyr: plyr-react
